# SPField.sortable returns actual value only after watching it in debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, spfield

Here is my method, that should return if field can be sorted:

```
public bool IsSortable(SPList list, string fieldName)
            {
                SPField field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldName);

                return field.Sortable;
            }
```

It always returns `true`. But if I add a breakpoint before `return` and look at the properties of the field in watch window (Visual Studio 2013) in debug mode it shows me actual value of the property (`true` or `false`). And after that on continue method `IsSortable` returns actual value.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads running in this application, accessing this property?

Comment: @Alex, I send `JQuery` ajax request from client to the method on server in which `IsSortable` is called